# Sharepoint 2013 + ASP.NET Web API

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-web-api

Можно ли реализовать RESTful сервис на ASP.NET Web API при разработке для Sharepoint?

Comment: SharePoint Online или свой сервер?

Comment: Свой Sharepoint сервер.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здравствуйте! 
В общем то можно, но он не будет встроен в SharePoint. 
Т.е. Ваш web api проект будет "рядом".
Опишите подробнее задачу для более конкретного ответа.